# Validating user input based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress text field package_id in the CPT gd_place should accept data only from a finite list of known and trusted values which are different depending on user e.g. role_one can only input 1, role_two can only input 2, role_tree only 3.

I first wrote this function, hiding the input field with css

```
function safe_package( $data ) {
if( 'gd_place' != $data['post_type'] ){
    return $data;
    //This is for one CPT only
}

$user = wp_get_current_user(); 
if(!is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator')){
    //Does NOT run in the backend and also takes the admin role into account
    if(current_user_can('role_one')){
    $data['package_id'] = 1;
    return $data;
    }
    else if (current_user_can('role_two')){
    $data['package_id'] = 2;
    return $data;
    }
    else if (current_user_can('role_three')){
    $data['package_id'] = 3;
    return $data;
    }

} else {
    //do nothing new
    return $data;
}

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'safe_package' );
```

But then it might make more sense to just validate the user input (whitelist) and update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'package_id', $safe_package );

As the options are finite per user role maybe just replacing any wrong input would make sense... anyone familiar with validation?